# Why does Dockerfile RUN print echo options?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using latest Docker for Mac, on latest macOS.

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -y -q \
    && apt-get install -y -q apt-utils \
    && apt-get upgrade -y -q \
    && apt-get install -y -q ssh build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-pip python-six openjdk-7-jdk \
    && mkdir -p /etc/ansible \
    && echo -e "[ssh_connection]\nssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPersist=60s\n" > /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

The problem is with the echo command. The content of the file produced by that command is:

```
-e [ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPersist=60s
```

The -e option is printed as well! What's even crazier the option has been picked up by echo, as evident by the newlines being parsed. In fact if I attach to a container and run the same command again, I get the correct file content. I thought this might be a problem with `docker build` quoting each argument in RUN, but even if I run `echo "-e" "X\nY"` the command prints:

```
X
Y
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try running:

```
RUN bash -c 'echo -e ...'
```

[Source](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8949)

Comment: I just replaced `echo` with `/bin/echo`, because I don't wanna deal with double quoting.

Comment: Nope, still just get a stupid literal line that shows exactly what I put in the Dockerfile, it doesn't reveal what the value is at all.

Answer (score 2):

Reading carefully https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8949, I understand that the reason of the weird behavior depends from the interpreting shell.

In my case, running an Ubuntu image, it was enough to remove the **-e** to have the line properly formatted:

```
RUN echo "# User rules for foobar\n\
            foobar ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/nopasswd
```

And the result is:

```
# User rules for foobar
            foobar ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Answer (score -10):

Better not to use double quote in `RUN`. Always use single quote or use `ENV` variable to set environment variables.

ex:

```
echo '******* Installing PPA pack ********'

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: This is not what the poster is asking, nor (I believe) is it valid Dockerfile syntax